# Interfacing a RAM chip from a commercial computer with an ARM cpu such as Stm32

Tags: stm32, embedded, arm, ram, ddr2

I need to interface some sort of RAM with an ARM processor for my embedded project. Around 128 MB to be exact. I found a [computer RAM](https://www.banggood.com/1GB-PC3200-DDR-400MHz-333-266-Desktop-PC-DIMM-Memory-RAM-184-pin-p-918849.html) which claims to be DDR and 1 GB. As I only need 128 MB of RAM for my project, can I just get those individual chips from the RAM and use it in my project? Or is some sort of external circuitry a must? I want to access it through the address and the data bus.

Comment: Which STM32? You must check first if it has DDR support before you can connect it.

Comment: First you need to find a CPU with a RAM controller. Then find a open source SBC design as a starting point. But why not just buy something off the shelf from vendors like olimex?

Comment: If the speed isn't too important, I would look for something easy to interface, like SPI RAM. DDR RAM is designed for *speeeeeeed* so it's a bit complicated.

Comment: @user253751 The speed *is* important, but not too much. I am looking for something around 480 mhz.

Comment: If you're married to an STM32, then the only ones which wall talk to *DDR* SDRAM are the STM32MP1 devices. However if you can manage with non-DDR SDRAM then an STM32H7 can talk to a pair of [Winbond W989Dxxx](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/949/w989dxdb_pkg_datasheet_a01-002_20161201-1760425.pdf) devices which will give you a total of 128MB (1Gb). I hope you're confident routing high-speed PCBs ...

Comment: If this is for that game console project again, you probably only need something that outperforms the display update rate by a fair bit. Humans are dreadfully slow, they stop noticing things somewhere beyond 100Hz. So something like a 1 to 10 Mbps SPI to a SPI RAM is probably more than enough to cover whatever it is you need to update there. Use DMA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The individual chips are 128M × 4 bits, so the number of chips you need would depend on how wide you want your data bus to be. For example, if you want an 8-bit data bus, you'd need 2 chips.

If you want a full 32-bit data bus, you'll need 8 chips — half the chips on the module — so you might as well just get a module socket and plug the whole thing in.

You can get SDRAM chips that are up to 16 bits wide; you'd only need two of those to fill up the width of a 32-bit bus.